# select from an executed query

Tags: sql

Hi how do I select from an executed query? Can't seem to get it to work.

I have the following:

```
    declare @query = 
    '
    declare @variable
    select name from accounts where @variable=blah blah blah
    '
```

then I have the following statement below my stored procedure,

```
select id from table where name in (exec(@query))
```

I cant use subquery because it gives me an error. I don't think declaring variables work on a subquery

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select id from table where name in(select name from accounts where blah blah)
```

Comment: the original query does not exactly look like that. I just simplified it. I need to be selecting from an execution of the query. What did i do wrong above?

Comment: @aedz - even if original query is not like above , you can use following method. OR you can use join. To write join query i need to know your table structure

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the above Query using **[Sub-Query](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm)**

```
select id from table 
where name in
           (select name from accounts where blah blah)
```

And no matter how **complex** is your `Sub-Query`, it will give the **Result**.

Comment: the reason i'm doing this is because i dont think that declaring variables work in subquery's. or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

solved it using the ff

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@body varchar(max) output', @body = @result output
```